# Why I'm unable to listen to a socket.io event from a React/ReactNative Client app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I'm new to socket.io and I used it with both react and react native. In my scenario Server emits an ‘incomingBooking’ event. So client needs to catch this event and print ‘booking details’ in console.

I tried as follows, but it didn't work for me.

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

    componentDidMount () {
        const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/riders");
        const username = "pawan@gmail.com";
        const data = {
            username: username,
            room: username,
            location: {
                latitude: 6.8741,
                longitude: 79.8605,
            }
        }
        socket.emit('joinRoom', {room: username});
        socket.emit('updateLocation', data);

        socket.on('incomingBooking', function (details) {
            console.log('Booking!!!', details);
        });

        console.log("Done")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Drawer/>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe how you send information from server?

This example should work fine:

```
//server.js
const io=require('socket.io')();
io.on('connect',(socket)=>{
    console.log('socket connected');
    socket.on('updateLocation',(msg)=>{
        console.log('updateLocation request');
        socket.emit('incomingBooking',{
            test:'data'
        })
    })
})
io.listen(3000)
```

Pay attention: while you are using `socket.on('eventName')` on the client side, you must use `socket.emit('eventName')` on server side, `socket.send('something')` wouldn't work.

Comment: I have solved it. there is an issue with booking object format. Thanks for your answer.